# Anchoring Table (Tabularx) from the Bottom of Table

Tags: tables, vertical-alignment, enumerate, tabularx

Can you anchor a table at the bottom, inline with text?

I have another question posted which I seemed to have solved myself - [List Numbering Through Multiple Tables](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/168161/list-numbering-through-multiple-tables) - but I have since found my way around this original problem, into another.

My goal, depicted in the image below, is to create a multicolumn math test. The problem I have is aligning the question # with the answer choices (See image below MWE for current result). In my MWE my #2 label is midway up the rectangle instead of by the answer choices below "Column A" and "Column B."

Using automatic question numbering is essential. I do not want to have to input question numbers manually.

[image: Goal - Correct Question Number Alignment]

MWE:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,twoside,openright]{memoir}
\usepackage[bmargin=1in]{geometry}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

\usepackage{enumitem}
    \newlist{ptestlist}{enumerate}{2}
    \setlist[ptestlist]{label={\arabic*.},itemsep=5mm,labelsep=3mm,topsep=1cm}

\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{tabularx}
    \newcolumntype{Y}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
{\LARGE Part One --- Word Problems}
\end{center}

\textbf{Directions:} Choose the best answer from the four choices given.

\hrulefill
%-----------        Questions           --------------% 
\setlength{\columnsep}{50pt}
\begin{multicols}{2}
\begin{ptestlist}[series=ptest,labelsep=0pt]
\item \begin{tabularx}{3in}{YY}
      \underline{Column A}
      &
      \underline{Column B}
      \\
      $6 + 4 - 5 \times 6$
      &
      34
      \\
      \end{tabularx}

\item \begin{tabularx}{3in}{YY}
      \multicolumn{2}{c}
      {
      \begin{tikzpicture}
      \draw (-1.85,0) node [rectangle,draw,minimum size=1in,
                            label=below:$2x$,label=right:$x$] (rsquare) {};
      \draw (1.75,0) node [rectangle,draw,minimum size=.8in,
                            label=below:$2y$,label=right:$y$] (lsquare) {};
      \end{tikzpicture}
      } \\
      \underline{Column A}
      &
      \underline{Column B}
      \\
      34
      &
      34
      \\
      \end{tabularx}

\item \begin{tabularx}{3in}{YY}
      \underline{Column A}
      &
      \underline{Column B}
      \\
      34
      &
      34
      \\
      \end{tabularx}

\item \begin{tabularx}{3in}{YY}
      \underline{Column A}
      &
      \underline{Column B}
      \\
      34
      &
      34
      \\
      \end{tabularx}
\end{ptestlist}

\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

This code gets me here:
[image: MWE Result - Incorrect]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use

```
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}[b]{YY}
```

to set the `tabularx` to be aligned to the `b`ottom. Using `\linewidth` makes it fit within the column width, even with `\item`:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

It sounds like you might like the [`adjustbox`](http://texdoc.net/pkg/adjustbox) package, which can be used as follows

```
    \item \begin{adjustbox}{valign=t}\begin{tabularx}{3in}{YY}
```

[image: screenshot]

Here's a complete MWE:

```
% arara: pdflatex
\documentclass[letterpaper,twoside,openright]{memoir}
\usepackage[bmargin=1in]{geometry}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

\usepackage{enumitem}
    \newlist{ptestlist}{enumerate}{2}
    \setlist[ptestlist]{label={\arabic*.},itemsep=5mm,labelsep=3mm,topsep=1cm}

\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{tabularx}
    \newcolumntype{Y}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}

\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
{\LARGE Part One --- Word Problems}
\end{center}

\textbf{Directions:} Choose the best answer from the four choices given.

\hrulefill
%-----------        Questions           --------------% 
\setlength{\columnsep}{50pt}
\begin{multicols}{2}
\begin{ptestlist}[series=ptest,labelsep=0pt]
\item \begin{tabularx}{3in}{YY}
      \underline{Column A}
      &
      \underline{Column B}
      \\
      $6 + 4 - 5 \times 6$
      &
      34
      \\
      \end{tabularx}

    \item \begin{adjustbox}{valign=t}\begin{tabularx}{3in}{YY}
      \multicolumn{2}{c}
      {
      \begin{tikzpicture}
      \draw (-1.85,0) node [rectangle,draw,minimum size=1in,
                            label=below:$2x$,label=right:$x$] (rsquare) {};
      \draw (1.75,0) node [rectangle,draw,minimum size=.8in,
                            label=below:$2y$,label=right:$y$] (lsquare) {};
      \end{tikzpicture}
      } \\
      \underline{Column A}
      &
      \underline{Column B}
      \\
      34
      &
      34
      \\
      \end{tabularx}
    \end{adjustbox}

\item \begin{tabularx}{3in}{YY}
      \underline{Column A}
      &
      \underline{Column B}
      \\
      34
      &
      34
      \\
      \end{tabularx}

\item \begin{tabularx}{3in}{YY}
      \underline{Column A}
      &
      \underline{Column B}
      \\
      34
      &
      34
      \\
      \end{tabularx}
\end{ptestlist}

\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

Comment: maybe I've missed the point...